# Azure API returns generic error for timeout

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I need to set a timeout at the api level, I used this

```
<forward-request timeout="3">
```

I added wait() in the micro-service to test this change, and it is working as expected.

The problem is in the error returned, it is so generic

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error",
    "activityId": "xxxxxxxx"
}
```

How to make it be more specific (timeout error)?

Update 1:
I have found a solution for this problem by adding this

```
<on-error>
    <set-body>
        @(
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("MsgRsHdr",new JObject(new JProperty("status", "ERROR"))),
                new JProperty("content",new JObject(
                    new JProperty("errors",
                        new JArray(
                            new JObject(
                                new JProperty("code", context.Response.StatusCode.ToString()),
                                new JProperty("message", context.LastError.Message),
                                new JProperty("Reason", context.LastError.Reason),
                                new JProperty("Source", context.LastError.Source),
                                new JProperty("Scope", context.LastError.Scope),
                                new JProperty("Section", context.LastError.Section),
                                new JProperty("Path", context.LastError.Path),
                                new JProperty("PolicyId", context.LastError.PolicyId),
                                new JProperty("type", "Error")
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    new JProperty("timestamp",DateTime.UtcNow)
                    )
                )
            ).ToString()
        )
    </set-body>
</on-error>
```

For me this seems to be a work-around, and not the intended way to return a more meaningful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind default behavior is that you're in control of how much detail you want to expose to clients calling your API. Clients are not always in your control. Look into set-body with template to make error response easier to read in policy.